# How do I wait on a condition without it being a race condition?

Tags: c, pthreads

If you run the code as is, you'll likely have no problems. The problem is if broadcast happens before cond_wait this code no longer works. If you uncomment the sleep below you'll encounter the problem every run

How do I write this so there's no race condition? I happen to know I can solve this using futex but I'm looking for a pthread solution

```
//clang++ -g -fsanitize=undefined,thread main.cpp && ./a.out
#include <cstdio>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
pthread_mutex_t write_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t checkpoint = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int data;

void*fn(void*) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&write_lock);
    auto temp = ++data;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&write_lock);
    
    //This if makes it so no thread will pass until both/all threads have finished writing to data
    if (temp < 2) {
        //sleep(1); // <--------- uncomment to see problem
        while (temp < 2)
        {
            pthread_mutex_t local_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&local_mutex);
            pthread_cond_wait(&checkpoint, &local_mutex);

            //Recheck the condition
            pthread_mutex_lock(&write_lock);
            temp = data;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&write_lock);
        }
    } else {
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&checkpoint);
    }
    
    int sum=data; //no way to get here until both/all threads execute the sync code
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread_id[2];
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_create(&thread_id[i], &attr, &fn, 0);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread_id[i], 0);
    }
    printf("Finish\n");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `local_mutex`?

Comment: @जलजनक pthread_cond_wait says it needs a mutex that's locked as its second parameter. I have no idea why it wants it

Comment: What's the objective for this program?

Comment: Nothing, it's an example of a bug. I'd like no threads to get to the end of the if statement until data is no longer being written to which is why I have the cond wait

Comment: *"I have no idea why it wants it"* - The mutex purpose is to protect the predicate data. That's *all*. The purpose of pairing with a cond-var is to ensure that the act of monitoring the cond-var for signal which indicates someone, somewhere, *may* have modified the predicate state, and releasing the mutex to to allow that someone, somewhere, to actually acquire it and safely make that modification, is *atomic* (at least as far as you're concerned). `local_mutex` isn't protecting *anything*, therefore, it's use with that cond-var is simultaneously as pointless as it is suspect.

Comment: @WhozCraig feel free to show me a solution

Comment: @जलजनक the answer shows why I need a mutex. For my usecase it made no sense because I didnt need to protect any data I only wanted to know if all my data has been processed so I can run some syncing code. It appears the mutex gets unlocked when it enters cond and locked again before the function returns and is used to make sure there's no race when a thread calls signal/broadcast

Comment: @EricStotch Note: the mutex is *not* to protect the condvar signal/broadcast. In the posted solution it is solely to protect `data`. That is the predicate artifact. It cannot be written *or read* without protection of the mutex. Remember, in pthread condvar/mutex duos, the mutex protects the predicate data; not the condvar. In fact, you'll notice that the last thing the thread does before exiting is signal the condvar to notify another potential waiter, and it does so *without* being under the protection of a latched mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm not clear on your real problem. This looks like you're attempting to stack up your client threads until such time as *all* of them have surpassed a specific checkpoint. In this case, that checkpoint is achieved once `data` has been bumped by all threads

Therefore, `data` holds your predicate state. Testing or writing it is the purpose of the mutex protection. *Change detection* is the purpose of the cond-var.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t write_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t checkpoint = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int data;

void *fn(void *pv)
{
    // construction-passed top limit
    intptr_t n = (intptr_t)pv;

    // changing predicate, so lock mutex
    pthread_mutex_lock(&write_lock);
    ++data;

    // changed predicate, so tell people.
    pthread_cond_signal(&checkpoint);

    // mutex is still locked. if our predicate state isn't
    //  sufficient to move on, we wait (and release the mutex
    //  in the process)
    while (data < n)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&checkpoint, &write_lock);

        // TODO: woke up here. may be spurious, may be legit, but
        //  we're going to make sure on the next iteration of the
        //  loop by rechecking the predicate data, which we can do
        //  because the mutex is locked coming out of the wait.

        // ALSO: if you want off-the-mutex processing here of some
        //  kind you would do it by releasing the mutex, do your
        //  thread work, then reacquire the mutex again before the
        //  next iteration of the loop
    }

    // NOTE: still own the mutex.
    
    // no way to get here until all threads execute the sync code
    //  note: not a legit use of pthread_self, use at your peril
    printf("%p : %d\n", (void*)pthread_self(), data);

    // leaving the party, release the mtx and tell someone.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&write_lock);
    pthread_cond_signal(&checkpoint);

    return 0;
}

#define N_THREADS   16

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id[N_THREADS];
    for (intptr_t i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, &fn, (void*)(intptr_t)N_THREADS);

    for (intptr_t i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(thread_id[i], 0);

    printf("Finish\n");
}
```

**Output** (example only)

```
0x7000019e9000 : 16
0x700001448000 : 16
0x700001342000 : 16
0x700001654000 : 16
0x7000016d7000 : 16
0x7000012bf000 : 16
0x70000175a000 : 16
0x7000013c5000 : 16
0x7000017dd000 : 16
0x70000123c000 : 16
0x700001860000 : 16
0x70000154e000 : 16
0x7000018e3000 : 16
0x7000014cb000 : 16
0x700001966000 : 16
0x7000015d1000 : 16
Finish
```

That is what it at-least seems you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you, I was extremely confused until I ran your code. So the reason this works is because pthread_cond_wait will unlock the mutex? I'll try this in my example so I'll need a few minutes. It's locking more code than I desire but this looks like the correct solution

Comment: I really dislike how pthread works. This solved it. Reducing the scope made it deadlock until I remembered why the signal should be within the lock. Accepted

Comment: *"So the reason this works is because pthread_cond_wait will unlock the mutex?"* - Yes, that is exactly what happens, it atomically (as far as you're concerned) both releases the mutex *and* begins the wait-for-signal on the condvar. **Never** invoke pthread_cond_wait with an unlocked mutex, and always remember that, coming out of a non-erroneous wait, the mutex is once-again locked.

Comment: What is your favorite threading API? I'm stuck with pthreads for the moment but maybe in another project or another language I can try it

Comment: For C, you pretty much already have it. pthreads is basically the de'facto api on all platforms except Windows (naturally), but there are some pthread shims for there too. But for me? I'm a C++ guy, and the thread primitives, including threads, mutexes, condvars, etc., added in C++11 onward are just the cats pajamas. Further, the async, future, and promise additions are all outstanding as well. That language and standard library took a **huge** leap forward in C++11. It was a *long* time coming and I was so damn happy when it finally did I could just about cry tears of joy.

Comment: I also really like C++ threading but I haven't used it in a real project yet. async I'm not sure how I feel about it because I never actually try to get performance out of C#/languages with async. In C# I really don't think about threading. ASP.NET just calls my code and I act like it's a single threaded app and don't use static variables and it seems all good. Callbacks... are a nightmare. I haven't done much with promises but I am not oppose to the syntax `do_thing(...).then(oneLayerOfCallback).error(easyHandling)`. I'm not sure why I haven't entered callback hell in that